# Passing checkbox to hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have a checkbox which is loading from php on other page and since i cannot get the values of them ive written a jquery script that was supposed to check if a checkbox was checked and if so it would mark the corresponding hidden input with value 1 or 0.
But seems like it's only working for 1 in the loop no matter what i do.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var total = <?php echo $count; ?>;
        for (i = 0; i < total; i++) { 
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(event) {
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    $(".check_"+i).val(1);
                    console.log("added"+i);
                }else{
                    $(".check_"+i).val(0);
                    console.log("removed"+i);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. if `total` is, for example, 10, then this code will attach 10 "change" events to **all** the checkboxes on the page. Can you show us the HTML which goes with it, then we can be clearer what the structure is?

Comment: are there multiple checkboxes present and for change event of one checkbox only one particular hidden input should change? Can you elaborate more and put relevant html also/

Comment: Yes checkboxes can be infinite as it is generating a new checkbox for each new user, they are generated by php on a loop aswell

Comment: ok, will there be any unique identifier for each checkbox and how it relates to hidden input (i mean how you identify which hidden input to change value)? It would be better if you can put relevant html with checkbox and input hidden fields

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Kawadkar .    Yes every checkbox is identified uniqly by id and name for example #check_0 , #check_1, #check_2 and the hidden inputs identified by class : .check_0, .check_1  and if the jquery detect checkbox #check_1 was checked then we make hidden input .check_1 value 1 otherwise 0

Comment: Another question - why do you need the hidden field at all, if you only want to duplicate the status of the related checkbox? What is the purpose of it? Why not read the values from the checkboxes directly?

Comment: @ADyson The thing is that the input fields are loaded from a php class extenal file which are then placed inside a table(Imagine a table with a users from database in a loop, each of them contains a checkbox) , but the problem is that i need the form outside the table and seems like it will not send the form unless its outside as even if i started the form inside the loop of the users the button that was out side was not going to submit, that's why i need a hidden input that reads thoose checkboxes

Comment: @Goncalo "if i started the form inside the loop" ...then you'll get lots of forms, so no that's probably not a good approach. But I would expect there's nothing stopping you from starting your form _before_ the `<table>` and ending it in some place _after_ the `</table>`. Alternatively, in HTML5 you can declare an `input` element outside a `<form>` tag and then associate it to the form by adding a `form` attribute to it - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes . In that situation you just need to make sure the form has an ID

Comment: @ADyson I know , sorry, i explained badly , i meant in the external file but not inside the loop. Your suggestion i already tried bud somehow if i place the form above table and below the submit button does not submit anything, simply does not submit

Comment: @Goncalo do you get any JavaScript errors in your Console when you try to press the button? have you ensured that you don't have `<form>` inside another `<form>` (because that is not allowed)? Without seeing exactly what you tried it's hard to say exactly what the problem is. But personally I would say it's better to just include the checkboxes directly in the form than make a workaround involving hidden fields - it's less complicated to write and maintain. Perhaps you should ask a new question about the form problem instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are registering change event handler of checkbox for multiple times instead you need to put 1 or 0 on multiple i=hidden inputs.
You don't need loop here, just add change event handler for all checkboxes having id starts with `check_` and read same id to create input hidden class selector. Set the value to input hidden.

See below code -

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //bind change event for checkbox having id starts with "check_"
        $(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"][id^=check_]', function(event) {
             var id = $(this).attr('id');// id of checkbox checked/unchecked
             $("."+id).val($(this).is(':checked')?1:0); // put 1 or 0 to the matching hidden input
        });           
    });
</script>
```

Comment: not sure about this either... in this case, if _any_ checkbox is checked, then it will update _all_ the hidden fields with 1. Not sure that's likely to be the OP's intent. There needs to be a relationship between each checkbox and hidden field, perhaps based on IDs, classes or data-attributes.

Comment: I have put query on post to clarify more, you might be correct.. lets see what OP says

Comment: Thanks for your input but this does not work aswell as it for example if i mark check_2 it will always say it was check_0

Comment: `check_2` is this an id or class of checkbox?

Comment: I mean on console log, it always marks as if it was the first row of the loop to be changed

Comment: Now its working!! Thanks alot for this mate @BhushanKawadkar

Comment: happy to help you :)